# Excel on Sharepoint: Chart not show

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

Just uploaded a PowerPivot Workbook to a PowerPivot Gallery on Sharepoint 2013 site. I opened it but only the slicers are shown, not the Pivot chart.

At the position of the pivot chart, there is only an [x] icon.

Apart from that, I don't see any notice, error information or similar.

I'm the admin of both SharePoint farm and SQL Server.

I googled but did not find anything, not sure what I missed.

Edit 1: Menu bar also not work, not thing haoppend when click, i think there is something wrong with my excel application on sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

1. Chart not show : Change value of **Maximum Chart or Image Size** in Trusted File Location of Excel Service Application
2. Menu Bar not work : use FireFox + IETab addon